# How to get number of duplicate Rows of DISTINCT column as another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I make the following Column

```
------------
MakeDistinct
------------
CAT
CAT
CAT
DOG
DOG
PIN
PIN
PIN
PIN
```

As Shown Below

```
-------------   -------
AfterDistinct   Count
-------------   -------
CAT              3
DOG              2
PIN              4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` function by grouping `MakeDistinct` column using `GROUP BY` clause.

```
  SELECT MakeDistinct AS AfterDistinct
       , COUNT(MakeDistinct) AS Count
    FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MakeDistinct
```

Output:

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════╗
║ AFTERDISTINCT ║ COUNT ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════╣
║ CAT           ║     3 ║
║ DOG           ║     2 ║
║ PIN           ║     4 ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e2f0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select 
    MakeDistinct AfterDistinct, 
    COUNT(*) [Count] 
from 
    YourTable
group by MakeDistinct
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MakeDistinct AS AfterDistinct, COUNT(*) AS [COUNT] FROM tablename 
GROUP BY MakeDistinct
```