# How can I use sql Aggregate functions in C# DataTable

Tags: c#

I want to apply the follwing Sql query in my DataTable

```
SELECT MakeDistinct AS AfterDistinct
       , COUNT(MakeDistinct) AS Count
    FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MakeDistinct
```

Refer this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562862/how-to-get-number-of-duplicate-rows-of-distinct-column-as-another-column) for more details

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is the problem ?

Comment: You can't... just run the query in the linked question accepted answer and save it into another datatable, or loop on your existing datatable to do the count, eventually using the rowfilter property...

Comment: in c# DataTable if I use `DataTable.Select()` method I can define only the clause after where condition. I want a result set with new column as mentioned in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562862/how-to-get-number-of-duplicate-rows-of-distinct-column-as-another-column

Comment: ooooh DataTable don't know about computation. go thru Linq queries

Comment: @Jodha I didn't mean it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like:

```
var query = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row.Field<int>("MakeDistinct") into grp
            select new {AfterDistinct = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count()};

foreach(var row in query) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", row.AfterDistinct, row.Count);
}
```

Note that aggregating at the database server will usually be much more efficient than populating a `DataTable` over the network and then aggregating the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 1):

You are partially looking for [`DataTable.Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx). That method can calculate aggregate functions for you. So you get something like:

```
object sumObject;
sumObject = myDataTable.Compute("Sum(Count)", ""); // second parameter is the where clause
```

For grouping by columns, see this question: [Efficient DataTable Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472005/efficient-datatable-group-by). It provides a Linq implementation as well as a 'non-Linq' implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Use *System.Data.DataSetExtensions* and try something like this

```
var result = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
              group row by row.Field<int>("MakeDistinct") into grp
              select new
                 {
                    MakeDistinct = grp.Key,
                    Count = grp.Count()
                 };
```